# How to test Vue prop update in Jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I'm new to Jest and trying to write a test for my Vue app that would confirm a child component emits an event and as a result, its prop value gets updated.

As an example I've made a simple app with a counter to demonstrate:

```html
/* Parent Home.vue */
<template>
  <Counter :count="count" @increment="count++"/>
</template>

<script>
import Counter from "@/components/Counter.vue";
export default {
  components: { Counter },
  data: () => ({
    count: 0,
  }),
};
</script>
```

```html
/* Child Counter.vue */
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div id="propTracker">{{ count }}</div>
    <v-btn ref="incrementProp" @click="increment($event)">Increase prop</v-btn>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["count"],
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$emit("increment");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Once the button in `Counter` is pressed, it should emit an `increment` event to increment the count in parent `Home` component.

This is the test I've written:

```js
  it("Click should increment count text", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Counter, {
      localVue,
      vuetify,
      propsData: { count: 0 },
    });

    expect(wrapper.find("#propTracker").text()).toBe("0"); //initial state

    const button = wrapper.find({ ref: "incrementProp" });
    await button.trigger("click"); //trigger click

    expect(wrapper.find("#propTracker").text()).toBe("1"); //after click
  });
```

It returns back as `Expected: "1" Received: "0"` indicating that the prop update is not processed within the test. I've tried to combine many resources such as Vue guidelines [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-asynchronous-behavior) and Vuetify unit test info [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing/#spec-tests), yet it keeps coming back the same. I'm missing a puzzle piece and been looking for it for 2 days now.

This is a simplified [repo](https://github.com/anzuj/jest-test/tree/simplified) to have a better picture and perhaps play around locally.

A test to see if incrementing works with local data values worked fine: [here](https://github.com/anzuj/jest-test/blob/simplified/tests/unit/counter.spec.js#L47), so it's really the scenario with props and emitting that bums me out at the moment. Any help would be worth its weight in gold!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally found a solution! I went the wrong way about things and tried to test parent data changes in a child component. With the composition I have (child component Counter emits an event and triggers a change in parent Home component), this is the working test:

```js
  it("Counter button changes count in Home", () => {
    const wrapper = mountFactory(Home);

    //check if initial count in Home is 0
    expect(wrapper.vm.count).toBe(0);

    //click btn in Counter (child component)
    wrapper.find("#incrementBtn").trigger("click");

    //check if increment worked and count has increased
    expect(wrapper.vm.count).toBe(1);
  });
```

Learning curve to think in "Jest" :)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your repository and did the tests and everything worked fine. with the exception of the title that did not have a defined variable.
See print: https://puu.sh/GKmzu/69a9fe9f0a.png

Comment: Thank you for noticing this! And sorry about the title error, forgot to remove it from the simplified version but fixed it now in [home](https://github.com/anzuj/jest-test/blob/simplified/src/views/Home.vue). 

Just to clarify, the first 2 tests came back positive for you after running `npm run test`? Could you perhaps make a screenshot of the test terminal? (the one you linked is from the browser)

Comment: There really is an error when executing npm run test
see screenshot: https://puu.sh/GKpIk/75c60c8dd8.png

Comment: Yes, that's the same result I have, which is why I've made this ticket

Answer (score 0):

I think you should test just if the event is emitted. See that if you test for the local counter, the test will pass, but not for the prop count. That's because the test is not seeing the code on the Home component. Remember this is a unit test, the goal is to test the component in isolation.

Comment: Thank you for this! How about making a unit test for the parent component (Home), seek out child component (Counter) within the test, trigger the emit from the child component and then check if the data value in Home changed as a result?

Answer (score 0):

In general, for these kind of problems, you can simply use `setProps`.

docs: https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#setprops